# Using my Motherboard's VGA connector instead of my graphics card's

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, display, vga

I recently got a new graphics card but it doesn't have a VGA connector. Is there a way of configuring my PC so that it uses my motherboard's VGA connector instead?

For those wondering, my graphics card only came with an S-Video and a DMS-59 connector, neither of which is compatible with my monitor.

Edit: I wasn't very clear on my original post. Basically, I want to use my new graphics card but it doesn't have any connectors that are compatible with my monitor. Is there a way to use my onboard's VGA connector for display but still have the new GPU do all the graphics processing?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to use the an on-board output and have the discrete graphics card do the work. But maybe you can look for an adapter, I think I saw some DMS-59 - 2xVGA cables once.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Buy an [adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200208&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA)
2. Remove the card and use your onboard card.

Comment: You should do #1, especially if plan on playing games / doing GPU intensive stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option in the BIOS for which display to use first - onboard or AGP/PCI/etc. Try changing that and see what happens.

Comment: Well I still want to use my new graphics card, it just doesn't have a connector that's compatible with my monitor. So, I was wondering if I could use my onboard graphics card's connector but still have the new GPU do all the processing.

Comment: It might be possible to offload things like video transcoding to the card if it supports it, but I don't know of any way to do what you're asking (actually, I do remember with some 3D cards circa 1996 you'd connect the vga output of your standard or onboard graphics to the 3D card,  then plug the output of that to your monitor. But I don't think you can do that here. Get an adapter for your card.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which graphics card you got. However in many cases you can not use the graphics processing of the new card and still use the on-board connector. Either you use the on-board connector and the on-motherboard or on-APU's processing power, or you use one of the connectors on the new graphics card  and the new cards graphics processing power.

In your case: Use the old on-board connector, then check the manual it your new graphical card supports either DMS-59 to 2x DSUB (as in the image below) or DMS-59 to something else which you can convert to an analog Dsub signal.

[image: DMS-59_to_2xDSUB.png]

Technically an other alternative it to replace the monitor. The VGA standstand itself is ancient. It is from 1987. Since then it has been replaced on most (non-elcheapo) monitors by DVI. And DVI has already been replaced by DisplayPort and HDMI

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your edit, no, you can't "pipe" your cards output to your onboard VGA. You'll need to get an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes!

it's possible. I'm  not sure if it's possible to do that for systems using an Nvidia GPU, but I've tested it on a system using an AMD GPU and it worked fine.
There is a way to run all your GPU demanding processes (like games or any other application that uses graphical rendering) through the GPU but still get the output from the VGA output on the motherboard.

specs of the system I've tested it with:
MB: Biostar mhv3
CPU: Intel Core i5 4460
GPU: Radeon RX 480 8G
RAM: 2X8GB DDR3 1600

Take these actions step by step and you might be lucky:

1- Backup all your files and get ready to install a fresh windows10 (2004 build preferred)

2- Remove your GPU from motherboard PCI slot and connect your cable directly to
the onboard VGA output of your motherboard

3- Go to BIOS settings by pressing 'Delete' repeatedly right after restarting, when you're
in BIOS settings screen, find Intel HD Graphics settings, (if you can't find it google
it) it's default state might be set to Auto or Disabled, change it's state to Always
Enabled. then save and exit.

4- Turn system off and plug your GPU back into the motherboard PCI slot but your cable
should still remain connected to the onboard VGA output. make sure that
the power cable (6 pin or 8 pin) remains unplugged from the GPU, don't worry it won't
get damaged. otherwise you might get a black screen which won't let you proceed to the
next steps.

5- Start installing windows10

6- When finished installing, install latest Intel HD graphics driver among with other
drivers for your chipset but not the GPU driver yet, then restart the system.

7- After restarting, log back into the windows and you see that Intel HD graphics is now
your primary display. now turn off system completely, then plug the power cable
into the GPU

8- Turn on system and install latest stable (not beta) version of AMD GPU driver knows as
AMD Radeon Software (version 20.4.2 preferred) or the latest NVIDIA GeForce Graphics
Driver (456.71 WHQL preferred).

9- If installation was successful, make a restart to finish installation of it. you should
now be able to fully utilize your GPU in
running games and other graphical processing apps while getting the output from your
onboard VGA without the need to use an adapter to use the output on GPU.

NOTE: I hope it works for you, it did work for me. but again, about Nvidia GPUs I'm not
sure if it works or not, you can test it yourself to find out.